# Self adjoint, positive definite, non elliptic operator on Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I'm trying to find an example of a Hilbert space and a self adjoint, positive definite operator $A\in L(H)$ that is not elliptic. A suggestion given is to look at the space of square summable sequences $\ell^{2}$ and a linear operator that dilates the $n$th standard basis vector $e_{n}=\mathbb{I}[n=i]$ by a small positive factor. I still cannot see how to achieve this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose your definition of "positive definite" is $\langle A\xi,\xi\rangle>0$ for $\xi\neq 0$ and for "elliptic" $\inf_{\|\xi\|=1}\langle A\xi,\xi\rangle>0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct for positive definite.The definition I have for elliptic is defined on normed spaces but I think it is equivalent to the one you gave when looking at Hilbert spaces. $A:V\rightarrow V'$ (where $V'$ is the dual space) is elliptic if there exists $c>0$ such that $\langle Av|v\rangle\geq c||v||^2,\forall v\in V $

Comment: Also, $\langle Av|v\rangle=(Av)(v)$ (I'm not sure how common this notation is).

Comment: An easy example would be to define $A$ on the basis by $A e_n = 2^{-n}e_n$, right?